# find value of convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

I have to compute the value of convergent series:
\begin{eqnarray}
 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-i+2)^{2n}}{(2n)!}
\end{eqnarray}
I know that:
\begin{eqnarray}
 e^{z}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{n}}{n!}
\end{eqnarray}
so I have that:
\begin{eqnarray}
 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-i+2)^{2n}}{(2n)!}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(3-4i)^{n}}{(2n)!}
\end{eqnarray}
but I'm stuck, I compute this series on Wolfram and say that value is $\frac{1}{2}e^{3-4i}$, I don't know why

Comment: The sum is not equal to $\frac{1}{2}e^{3-4i}$. I suspect you might have entered $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(3-4i)^{n}}{2n!}$ into Wolfram, which does equal $\frac{1}{2}e^{3-4i}$. Are you familiar with any hyperbolic functions?

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake, and I find the serie for $\cosh z$. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Start with:

$\begin{align*}
  e^x
    &= \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{x^n}{n!} \\
  e^x - e^{-x}
    &= \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{x^{2 n}}{(2 n)!} \\
  \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{(2 - i)^{2 n}}{(2 n)!}
    &= e^{2 - i} - e^{-2 + i} \\
    &= e^2 (\cos (-1) + i \sin (-1)) - e^{-2} (\cos 2 + i \sin 1) \\
    &= e^2 (cos 1 - i \sin 1) - e^{-2} (\cos 2 + i \sin 1) \\
    &= (e^2 - e^{-2}) \cos 1 - i (e^2 + e^{-2}) \sin 1 
\end{align*}$

Comment: There's something wrong with your second equation. The sum of $\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$ is $\cosh(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$, not $e^x-e^{-x}$. If it helps you see the problem, notice that the series sums to $1$ when $x=0$ (this follows from the convention $0^0=1$), but $e^0-e^{-0}=0$.